# MySql sort varchar containing text + numeric data

Tags: mysql, sorting, varchar

I'd like to order by a varchar field that contains text and numeric data.

The values in the database / and also the order outputted with
  "ORDER BY CAST(`product` AS SIGNED)"

- Doppel 80x200cm
- Classic 100x200cm
- Mega 240x250
- Classic 85x200cm
- Profi 60x235cm

The ORDER I'd like to have is an order first by the text than by number:
(Please keep in mind that the productnames could be one of the following: Text only, Text+Number, Text+Number+Text)

- Classic 85x200cm
- Classic 100x200cm
- Doppel 80x200cm
- Mega 240x250
- Profi 60x235cm

I also tried the following without a correct result:
"ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(product,LOCATE(' ',product)+1) AS SIGNED) ASC"
  "ORDER BY CASE WHEN product REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' THEN product*1 else 999999 END"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Store the product name in a separate field, and the dimensions in two other fields.

Comment: @hjpotter92: I can't change the structure of the database, it's a closed system.

Answer (score 0):

This solution comes quite close. Off course you have to put the names in an php array first.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.natcasesort.php